# Running/Printing a report from VB6 application using ACCESS with data loaded from Sql

Tags: sql, vb6, report

I have a simple VB6 application where I input information and store it on SQL SERVER. I went ahead and linked Access 2007 and SQL Server so that all my tables are in Access for report generating purposes. I created a mock report, and was able to generate a report for all users from the sql Table (from Visual basic) Now my question is this, on the report form in the VB application, I have a combobox that's being populated with Client Names from the sql server. What I need to do is allow the user to choose a name from the combobox and click PRINT and allow them to only generate the report for that one user. The names in the combobox have ID's assigned to them. I'm having a hard time coming up with a way to edit the query in access (where id=17) from VB to allow the report to be only generated for one user. Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

Dont you think that sending a query from VB6 to Access would be a better way instead of modifying the queries in Access.

Hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Yah in this case i did it from vb6. Ive never done it before so i hadnt the clue where i shouldbhave done it.